# nwidart database module connection dont work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i have a problem my database connection down work

in my registerConfig() is this

```
$this->mergeConfigFrom(
            module_path($this->moduleName, 'Config/database.php'),
            'database.connections.core'
        );
```

in the `Config/database.php` this:

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'connections' => [
        'module1' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => '----',
            'port' => 3306,
            'database' => '----',
            'username' => '----',
            'password' => '----',
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_MODULE1_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ?
                array_filter([PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),]) : [],
        ],
    ],
];
```

when i will migrate comes `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Could not connect because the target computer refused to connect. (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

Why he will the database config from root project?

Comment: arent you merging `'database.connections.core'`?

Comment: What you mean? haha

Comment: hm I guess the first snippet refers to copying config TO `database.connections.core`. In any case, you should be able to debug the `config()` variable, and if that fails just start debugging the connection itself (there should be a `connection` property somewhere on the Eloquent query class as well if that is what produces the query. Just print it out using `dd()` and check its properties)

Comment: I have one other problem idk if you can help me. I go in the module folder and make a composer require package but now he say it needs illuminati and gruzzle etc but why how must I make that?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening here. You can make a separate `composer.json` in any of your modules and define your own Composer packages which you need in that module, but in the end it is part of a Laravel application (which is the `Illuminate/..` namespace) with a nwidart dependency, so it cannot run on its own. This is not a problem since the main `composer.json` (in the root of your project) should include all this stuff. You can create a new SO question if you need help on how to set this up (you have to define your modules as a local folder, so the dependencies get loaded properly)